# FirstOrDefault does not give appropriate answer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I tried fetching data from my table with entity framework with the help of `FirstOrDefault`.
The controller code is as follows:

```
public ActionResult getUser(MembershipModel model)
{
    ProviderImplementation.Edmx.ProviderEntities providerEntities = new ProviderImplementation.Edmx.ProviderEntities();
    //var membershipModel = new MembershipModel(); 
    //var model = ProviderImplementation.Models.MembershipModel;
    //bool isUserOnline = true;
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var isValid = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName, true);
        if (isValid != null)
        {
            var rowData = providerEntities.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(model.UserName)).FirstOrDefault();
            model.UserName = rowData.UserName;
            model.Password = rowData.Password;
            model.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(rowData.UserId);
            model.RoleId = Convert.ToInt32(rowData.RoleId);
            //var singleValue = providerEntities.Users.Find(model.UserName);
            ViewBag.User = "Found";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.User = "Not Found";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var error = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        ModelState.AddModelError("NoModelError", error.ToString());
    }
    return View(model);
  }
```

Also my table data are as follows:
Table Name: User

[image: Table containing Table data and columns]

Now I tried so many things it prints well the data in view with the specific record selected.

The problem is here:
{Works fine}--> 1. When I fetch the record with username "abbas" as it gets encountered first with UserId=2 it gets printed well in the view 
View code is:

```
  <div style="margin-left: 200px;">
    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            <th>Get User Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>@ViewBag.User</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserId)</td>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)</td>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)</td>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RoleId)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model=>Model.UserId)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model=>Model.UserName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model=>Model.Password)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model=>Model.RoleId)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

{Problem}--> 2. When I fetch the record with username "Abbas" having UserId=4 then FirstOrDefault prints the above data of UserName="abbas" as encountered first and does not print UserName="Abbas" in View.

**Note:
SingleOrDefault returns an exception telling that it found more than one instance.** 

Update:While debugging when I change the values it prints perfectly from the database.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit the question

Comment: ok i will read it and try to edit it as needed.

Comment: Firstly, you should drop the idea of having duplicate entries for user name. This should solve the very basic issue that you are facing and is the best practice for having user accounts data.

Comment: Ok but if i need it anyway for my application. Thus i need to find a solution to cope up with case sensitivity issue for my data. As i am working is such data structure there are going to be same names but with different case sensitives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the previous answers, you should not have a system that differentiates between usernames based on case sensitivity.  This is a sign that your structure is poorly designed, so I would suggest altering your system.  I can see for example you have roleid in the same table as the user table, if you are generating multiple logins on this table with different case sensitivity as a means to cope with different roles for the same person, there are far better ways to handle this which will cause you much less grief in the long run.

However, if you would like to check for case sensitivity then try:

```
var rowData = providerEntities.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == model.UserName && String.Compare(u.UserName, model.UserName,false) == 0);
```

You can also try the following (DB query):

```
var rowData = db.Users.ToList().Where(x => (string.Compare(x.UserName, model.UserName, false) == 0)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This assumes your User class is 'Users'.

Comment: I will just try and let you know the outcome. Yes i accept the advice about designing the proper table structure and will implement it from now on for other tables and also in other projects

Comment: No, its not working as expected. string comparison not working

Comment: I think it doesn't work because it is querying the database directly and a SQL table by default does not acknowledge case sensitivity.  So I have updated my answer with another possible solution which uses a call directly querying the database.  Give it a try.

Comment: I am using inbuilt microsoft sql server database file. I will give it a try and let the results be known to you. thanks for the tip

Comment: The ToList() loads all the records to memory. It's a wrong solution to load the entire table to memory and then perform the query. What is the take on performance when table size is huge. The query has to be best left to be executed by the DB, the sole purpose of having one.

Comment: @A Bittersweet Life - Yes I'm aware this will affect performance significantly, as I said in the response to the OP the only way to do what the OP is asking is to call directly to the DB, as far as I'm aware.  I don't agree in any way that this is what the OP should be doing.  However this is the correct answer to what he wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query behind the EF doesn't differentiate "abbas" / "Abbas". Please run SQL Profiler and see the query that executing on the call.

Comment: Can you give me a little brief about sql profiler. i want to know

Comment: I assume that your database is hosted in SQL Server. If your DB is hosted in SQL server, Microsoft SSMS provides a feature called "SQL Profiler" to trace all the queries targeting to your database. Please go through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff650699.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should drop the idea of having duplicate entries for user name. This should solve the very basic issue that you are facing and is the best practice for having user accounts data.

If you insist the user name can be duplicate then perform the `FirstOrDefault` with a case sensitive search. can you try the code snippet?

```
var rowData = providerEntities.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(model.UserName));
```

Comment: It isn't working. FirstOrDefault still doesn't differentiate between "abbas" & "Abbas".. uhhgg i am stuck!!...But the idea of FirstOrDefault with case sensitivity is good enough.